# convert Tue Jul 07 2019 12:30:42 to timestamp scala /spark

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark

I need to transform convert  `Tue Jul 07 2020 12:30:42` to timestamp with scala for spark.
So the expected result will be : `2020-07-07 12:30:42`

Any idea, how to make this please ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `to_timestamp` function.

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY") <-- Spark 3.0 Only.

df.withColumn("date", to_timestamp('string, "E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
  .show(false)

+------------------------+-------------------+
|string                  |date               |
+------------------------+-------------------+
|Tue Jul 07 2020 12:30:42|2020-07-07 12:30:42|
+------------------------+-------------------+
```